# XSLT 3.0 Streaming with Grouping and Sum/Accumulator

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I'm trying to figure out how to use XSLT Streaming (to reduce memory usage) in a scenario that requires grouping (with an arbitrary number of groups) and summing the group.  So far I haven't been able to find any examples.  Here's an example XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <Data>
    <Entry>
      <Genre>Fantasy</Genre>
      <Condition>New</Condition>
      <Format>Hardback</Format>
      <Title>Birds</Title>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <Genre>Fantasy</Genre>
      <Condition>New</Condition>
      <Format>Hardback</Format>
      <Title>Cats</Title>
      <Count>2</Count>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <Genre>Non-Fiction</Genre>
      <Condition>New</Condition>
      <Format>Paperback</Format>
      <Title>Dogs</Title>
      <Count>4</Count>
    </Entry>
 </Data>
```

In XSLT 2.0 I would use this to group by Genre, Condition and Format and Sum the counts.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:call-template name="body"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="body">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Data/Entry" group-by="concat(Genre,Condition,Format)">
      <xsl:value-of select="Genre"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="Condition"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="Format"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Count)"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For output I would get two lines, a sum of 5 for Fantasy, New, Hardback and a sum of 4 for Non-Fiction, New, Paperback.

Obviously this won't work with Streaming because the sum accesses the whole group.  I think I need to iterate through the document twice.  The first time I could build a map of the groups (creating a new group if one doesn't exist yet).  The second time  The problem is I also need an accumulator for each group with a rule that matches the group, and it doesn't seem you can create dynamic accumulators.

Is there a way to create accumulators on the fly?  Is there another/easier way to do this with Streaming?

Comment: Some thoughts: With XSLT 3.0 I wouldn't concatenate the elements you want to group by, instead I would use `xsl:for-each-group select="Data/Entry" group-by="Genre,Condition,Format" composite="yes"`. As for streamed grouping however, given that you want to use `group-by` with child elements all you could do is `<xsl:for-each-groups select="copy-of(Data/Entry)" group-by="Genre,Condition,Format" composite="yes"` as otherwise without using `copy-of` you could not select a child element in the `group-by` at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be able to use streamed grouping with XSLT 3.0 one option that I see is to first transform the element based data you have into attribute based data using a stylesheet like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Entry/*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then you can perfectly used streamed grouping (as far as a streamed `group-by` is possible at all, as far as I understand there will be some buffering necessary) as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:fork>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Data/Entry" composite="yes" group-by="@Genre, @Condition, @Format">
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), sum(current-group()/@Count)"/>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:fork>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know whether first creating an attribute centric document is an option but I think it is better to share suggestions with code in an answer instead of trying to put them into a comment. And the answer in [XSLT Streaming Chained Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937700/xslt-streaming-chained-transform) shows how to use Saxon 9 with Java or Scala to chain two streaming transformations without the need to write a temporary output file for the first transformation step.

As for doing it with `copy-of` on the original input format, Saxon 9.7 EE assesses the following as streamable and executes it with the right result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="copy-of(Data/Entry)" composite="yes"
            group-by="Genre, Condition, Format">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), sum(current-group()/Count)"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure it consumes less memory however than normal, tree based grouping. Perhaps you can measure with your real input data.

As a third alternative, to use a map as you seemed to want to do, here is an `xsl:iterate` example that iterates through the `Entry` elements, collecting the accumulated `Count` value in a map:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:iterate select="Data/Entry">
            <xsl:param name="groups" as="map(xs:string, xs:integer)" select="map{}"/>
            <xsl:on-completion>
                <xsl:value-of select="map:keys($groups)!(. || ' ' || $groups(.))" separator="&#10;"/>
            </xsl:on-completion>
            <xsl:variable name="current-entry" select="copy-of()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="key"
                select="string-join($current-entry/(Genre, Condition, Format), '|')"/>
            <xsl:next-iteration>
                <xsl:with-param name="groups"
                    select="
                        if (map:contains($groups, $key)) then
                            map:put($groups, $key, map:get($groups, $key) + xs:integer($current-entry/Count))
                        else
                            map:put($groups, $key, xs:integer($current-entry/Count))"
                />
            </xsl:next-iteration>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @RyanB, as you accepted the answer, I am curious for which approach did you settle with your real data?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the excellent answer.  I used the last approach which scales in memory usage with how many groups are output.

Comment: Very nice answers of xslt3, plus one.